# Pausing a bandcamp embedded player in Javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, carousel, html5-audio

Hey all I'm working on a project that would require the use of embedded players from bandcamp, youtube and soundcloud in a slideshow carousel.

I'm quite familiar with the youtube embed js api and the soundcloud one is by no means complicated but I can't seem to find any api for bandcamp that doesn't include getting an api key and invoking the api itself. I have no need for that. I just want to be able to pause the  player with Javascript if someone goes beyond that slide so there isn't the sound playing while the slide isn't showing.

Any ideas or places to look to interface just with the bandcamp embed widget?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack I worked around the issue.

Added a class="bandcamp_embed" to the embed iframe

and then using jQuery

```
$(".bandcampemb").each(function(i,t){
   var src_back = t.src;
   t.src = "random_blank.html";
   t.src = src_back;
});
```

I hope there is a better way in the future =]

Answer (score 0):

> I have no need for that.

I think Bandcamp has a need for that. With embed APIs, the idea is they want to host and control the content. As such, you will need to get an API key and access their API.